# Keyboard shortcut pass parameter

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-registry, context-menu

Is there a possibility to pass the current path as an argument when invoking a script via keyboard shortcut under Windows (interested in general, but specifically 10)?

It is possible to pass the path to an element in the context menu, so I wonder if I can do the same by using for example `Ctrl+B` in explorer.

Has anyone ever heard of a possibility to do this?

Comment: It seems very unnecessary

Comment: which context menu option

Comment: I mean the normal right mouse click context menu

Comment: I understand the context menu, the path is a parameter/arg to which option

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really get the question, so: I can add a context menu item with the command `cmd /c my.bat %V`. The bat will be called with the path where I selected the context menu item. I want this kind of parameter for a keyboard shortcut, so `my.bat` would be called with `%V` if I press `Ctrl+B`